# Discord.js members of all guilds in status

Tags: discord.js

Ive been wondering how to put the total amount of users with my bot in there server, IN the bots status,ive tried `client.guilds.cache` and `client.guilds.cache.size`
but both just return undefined in the status, any help would he appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To get all the members you can use:

```
client.users.cache.size
```

If you want only users (without bots) use:

```
client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size
```

Comment: yea but as i said, size is undefined and doesnt work

Comment: Can you attach a snippet of your code? Specifically the way you defined your client and the code you're trying to run.

Comment: ```client = new Discord.Client();```

Comment: ```client.on("ready", () =>{
 console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
client.user.setPresence({
status: "idle",
game: {
name: `${client.users.cache.size}`,
type: "WATCHING"
  }
  });
});```

Comment: Sorry keep seperating these comments  but if you want to see more lmk

Comment: What version of discord.js do you use?
Does `client.users.cache.size` return undefined everywhere or just in your status?

Also, can you try changing `client = new Discord.Client();` to:
`const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ "GUILDS" ] })`

Comment: v14 and ill try it right now

Comment: [TypeError:  Cannot read property ‘size’ of undefined] Is the error it causes

Comment: Since you're using v14 you need to change some stuff:
`const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')`

`const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
  ]
});`

The `GUILD_PRESENCES` is the intent that you need for this to work. Make sure to have the others as well since you need them.

Comment: ```[TypeError: Cannot read property ’Guilds’  of undefined]```

Comment: Make sure that your discord.js is at the latest version. `npm uninstall discord.js` `npm install discord.js`
You should also check your package.json and make sure that it says `"discord.js": "^14.1.2"`

Comment: Many more errors lol, its fine I dont *need* it in my status, thanks for helping tho